Connection between trigonometric ratios and similar triangles.
Working on:

Daniel J. Velleman. (2024). "Calculus: A Rigorous First Course" (p. 63)

The author explains:

Although we have not used right triangles to define the trigonometric functions, it is important to know how the functions can be used to relate the sides and angles in a right triangle. In the right triangle in Figure 1.25a,



We have $\cos \theta = \frac{a}{c}$, $\sin \theta = \frac{b}{c}$, and $\tan \theta = \frac{b}{a}$. You can see this by observing that triangle ABC in Figure 1.25a is similar to triangle QOR in Figure 1.25b. You can now read off $\cos \theta$ and $\sin \theta$ from the coordinates of the point Q, using the definitions of the cosine and sine functions.

My question is: why do the ratios $\frac{a}{c}$, $\frac{b}{c}$, and $\frac{b}{a}$ hold, and what's the relationship with similar triangles ?

In similar triangles, corresponding sides are always in the same ratio

The two triangles are similar (same angles) but not necessarily congruent. For the generic triangle on the left, the hypotenuse has length $c$, but for the right triangle embedded inside the unit circle (where the hypotenuse is a radius of the circle), it has length $1$. Hence, the scale factor between the two triangles is $c$.
If $c > 1$, then the triangle on the left is bigger and we scale down by a factor of $c$ to obtain the triangle on the right. If $c < 1$, then it’s smaller and we scale up by a factor of $c$. Either way, any linear measurement on the left must be divided by $c$ to obtain the corresponding measurement on the right.
So the correspondence looks like
\begin{align}
c & \longleftrightarrow \frac{c}{c} = 1 \\[4pt]
a & \longleftrightarrow \frac{a}{c} \\[4pt]
b & \longleftrightarrow \frac{b}{c}
\end{align}
Everything you can say about one triangle has a corresponding statement (scaled by $c$) on the other triangle. For example, since Pythagoras tells us that $a^2 + b^2 = c^2$, we have
$$
\Bigl(\frac{a}{c}\Bigr)^2 + \Bigl(\frac{b}{c}\Bigr)^2 = 1 
$$
or $\bigl(\cos\theta\bigr)^2 + \bigl(\sin\theta\bigr)^2 = 1$, which is usually written as $\cos^2\theta + \sin^2\theta = 1$.
Another example: since the leg is never longer than the hypotenuse: $|a| \leq c$, we know that
$$
\biggl\lvert \frac{a}{c} \biggr\rvert \leq 1, 
$$
which translates to $\bigl\lvert \cos\theta \bigr\rvert \leq 1$.
